# Multiple field on the html card at single page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRX6F.png)

I want to create the area marked in the picture. but i don't know how to do it. There must be more than one clickable area in a single card. I am using angularjs, thymeleaf, html, css.

Comment: read this document for angular https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To know to have the clicked effect on the tabs, you must use RouterLinkActive with Angular: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive